# 20.04 Beta to LTS

Tags: 20.04

I am currently running 20.04 (development branch).  Will this upgrade automatically to 20.04 LTS when it's released or is there some action I'll have to take to move to the LTS version?

Comment: It will. Develpment branch is off-topic here.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Pilot6 So I've shouldn't have answered it? Thought we're supposed to help. Where could it read all the rules? The answer has been 9 years old.... Still struggling to understand how this forum works.

Comment: This is not a forum but Q&A site. See https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic @kanehekili

Comment: @kanehekili Although the answers are about 9 years old but they still apply. There's nothing bad in posting an answer if you know that but you should avoid answering off-topic or duplicate questions (In this case, IMO question was more a duplicate than being off-topic). Questions with upvoted/accepted answers won't get deleted automatically by the system which I think sometimes create noise on the site and people visiting the site in future might not get what they really want.

Comment: @Kulfy, I concur. It is a duplicate question but not off topics.Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just installed the beta version. It seems to be a complete and mostly stable distribution. It updates normally and will continue so. (Just received 115 changed packages)
So the beta will turn into the LTS Version.

It is even possible to upgrade from 19.X to 20.04 beta. [see here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/ubuntu-20-04-release-features)